# Linux: get specific field from filename

Tags: linux, bash

I am currently learning linux bash scripting:

I have **files** in a **folder** with the following filename-pattern:

```
ABC01_-12ab_STRINGONE_logicMatches.txt
DEF02_-12ab_STRINGTWO_logicMatches.txt
JKL03_-12ab_STRINGTHREE_logicMatches.txt
```

I want to extract STRINGONE, STRINGTWO and STRINGTHREE as a list. To see, if my idea works, I wanted to echo my result to bash first.

Code of my bash-script (executed in the folder, where the files are located):

```
#!/bin/bash
for element in 'folder' do out='cut -d "_" -f2 $element | echo $out' done
```

Actual result:

```
error: unexpected end of file
```

Desired result:

```
STRINGONE
STRINGTWO
STRINGTHREE
(echoed in bash)
```

Comment: You're missing a bunch of `;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea you are doing is right. But the syntax of file globbing (looking for text files) and command substitution (running the `cut` command) is wrong. You need to do

```
for file in folder/*.txt; 
    # This condition handles the loop exit if no .txt files are found, and
    # not throw errors
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    # The command-substitution syntax $(..) runs the command and returns the
    # result out to the variable 'out'
    out=$(cut -d "_" -f3 <<< "$file")
    echo "$out"
done
```